# Javascript bug - Left bit shift returns wrong output

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

The case is the following:

```
/// returns 406913024, but should 417018740736
    alert(6363201 << 16);
```

What is wrong? I tried the same in ruby and it returns the correct value (http://www.miniwebtool.com/bitwise-calculator/bit-shift/?data_type=10&number=6363201&place=16&operator=Shift+Left)

Comment: Javascript uses a 32-bit int internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, you are dealing with 32-bit numbers.

`6363201 << 16` results in `110000100011000010000010000000000000000`, which are **39** bits. Shedding off the first **7** bits (since you are shifting from right to left, you end up with `00011000010000010000000000000000`, which a (binary) [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) of it will show you that is **406913024**, not 417018740736.

Comment: I have the same problem with Typescript. How to get the right number back? Does this mean that we can not perform this operation in JS and TS?

Comment: @mor222, I believe you have to find other ways to do that operation. This is a good place to start, bot the article and its comments: http://2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html?showComment=1341491439528

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from [`MDN Left Shift Operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#%3C%3C_%28Left_shift%29)

> This operator shifts the first operand the specified number of bits to
>   the left. Excess bits shifted off to the left are discarded. Zero bits
>   are shifted in from the right.

Quoting [`Bitwise Shift Operators`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_shift_operators)

> Shift operators convert their operands to 32-bit integers in
>   big-endian order and return a result of the same type as the left
>   operand. The right operand should be less than 32, but if not only the
>   low five bits will be used.

Binary of `6363201` is `11000010001100001000001`.

When you left shift `6363201 << 16`, it becomes `417018740736` which in binary is `110000100011000010000010000000000000000`

Now, 32 bits from the least significant bits are retained, the actual bits retained are `00011000010000010000000000000000` which corresponds to `406913024`